# How to change div or class or id?

Tags: theme, magento2.3.1

```
<main id="maincontent" class="page-main">
.....
</main>
```

I need to replace class and id here 
also can we change a whole tag like main to section or something else.
please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add this to your default.xml layout file.

```
<referenceContainer name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="add-ID" htmlClass="new-class-name"/>
```